# How do I hit a link without rendering the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if it is possible to hit an external link without rendering that page, instead staying on the page or re-rendering the current screen. Essentially the link I'd like to hit provides me an action, but I do not want the user to view that page.

Comment: Are you talking about [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))? You can create a link that doesn't go anywhere by creating an empty onclick function, and you can use jQuery to make an AJAX request to asynchronously load data from a database, etc.

Comment: This question needs improvement.  What it needs is not clear, and how the comment provided an answer isn't very straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it an Ajax call (remote: true) and ignore the result.

Answer (score 1):

using `:remote => true` should work and you can respond with js to show some message saying the action has been done successfully.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to